# Count deep nested tables

Tags: postgresql

From this SQL schemas I want to count the number of times a user is in a contest.

[image: schema SQL user has trials]

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trials_has_users tu ON (tu.users_id = '1')
LEFT JOIN trials AS t ON (t.id = tu.trials_id)
WHERE u.id = '1';
```

Previously, I have the expected number of lines, but I want to make a count

```
SELECT contest_total FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trials_has_users tu ON (tu.users_id = '1')
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id,
        COUNT(*) AS contest_total
    FROM
        trials
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
        id
) AS t ON (t.id = tu.trials_id)
WHERE u.id = '1';
```

Previously, have 6 rows want 1 (current user id) need `LIMIT 1` ?

```
SELECT contest_total FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trials_has_users tu ON (tu.users_id = '1')
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id,
        COUNT(*) AS contest_total
    FROM
        trials
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
        id
) AS t ON (t.id = tu.trials_id)
WHERE u.id = '1'
LIMIT 1;
```

I would like to receive the number of contests in which the user has participated. My query is right ?

Comment: `SELECT u.*, COUNT(DISTINCT t.contests_id) AS contest_total FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN trials_has_users AS tu ON tu.users_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN trials AS t ON t.id = tu.trials_id
WHERE u.id = 1 AND tu.users_id = 1 GROUP BY u.id ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thx `COUNT(DISTINCT t.contests_id)` <3

Answer (score 1):

As ypercube pointed out, you want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT t.contests_id)` here to get the unique count of contests per users. All credit goes to ypercube on this one, but for a readable version of the example query on how to do this:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(DISTINCT t.contests_id) AS contest_total 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN trials_has_users AS tu 
    ON tu.users_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN trials AS t 
    ON t.id = tu.trials_id 
WHERE u.id = 1 AND tu.users_id = 1 
GROUP BY u.id;
```